# Installing Postfix conflicts with MySQL-server package

Tags: rhel, postfix, mariadb

I had to install MySQL Server community on our server (team lead did not want MariaDB due to support or something). Therefor I removed MariaDB which in turn also removed Postfix.

Now I need to install Postfix because we need to relay emails. If I do a `yum install postfix` it also tries to install mariadb-libs, which conflicts with MySQL-Server. How can I install Postfix without using MariaDB? Or how can I solve this conflict?

OS: RHEL 7.1

Some of the conflict error messages:

```
Transaction check error:   
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/README from
install of mariadb-libs-1:5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file
from package MySQL-server-5.5.42-1.el7.x86_64   
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/Index.xml from install of
mariadb-libs-1:5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package
MySQL-server-5.5.42-1.el7.x86_64   
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/armscii8.xml from install of
mariadb-libs-1:5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package
MySQL-server-5.5.42-1.el7.x86_64  
file /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ascii.xml from install of
mariadb-libs-1:5.5.41-2.el7_0.x86_64 conflicts with file from package
MySQL-server-5.5.42-1.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: If you use `--replacefiles` option with `rpm` it should overwrite.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem some time ago.  I think I solved it by installing `mysql-libs` first, then Postfix.  I'll add more information as I retrieve it.

Comment: That unfortunately does not work. I already have MySQL server installed.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what behaviour have with RPM packaging, I suppose don't differ much from DPKG, but in Debian you can substitute an app with requirements from others, if you install another app with the same requirements.

Examples: 
- MySQL & MariaDB
- Exim & Postfix
...

Regards,

Comment: In both cases, it depends how the requirements are specified -- if they've been specified by explicit package name, then you can't swap one in for the other, of course.

But you CAN create  virtual RPM to shim one requirement out with another.  I've used this in the php53/php package name disco - and when Joe Orton changed 'apache' to 'httpd' for lulz - and it's a great way to avoid changing the distributed stuff AND accomplishing your particular software load goals.

Answer (score 0):

Try to install using:

```
rpm -ivh MySQL-shared-[version].rpm
```

Then you can try to remove mariadb:

```
yum remove mariadb*
```

Answer (score -2):

After Installing MySQL-shared package able to install Postfix.

```
rpm -ivh MySQL-shared-[version].rpm

yum install postfix
```